# Bang & Olufsen audio issue on HP laptops

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hp, realtek

First of all I'd like to start off with the basic information regarding audio for HP laptops which previously shipped with Beats Audio and now with Bang & Olufsen.

- There is sound crackling in the left earphone when
  earphones/headphones are connected. This issue already has a
  [solution](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1648183/comments/17).
- The other issue is that the speakers(of the laptop)
  does not sound full. And some people say that the subwoofer is not working (the *pin* is not connected). A [post on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/17sov5/howto_beats_audio_hp_laptop_speakers_on/) contains the
  solution, but that is for older devices with Beats Audio, and **none
  exists** for the newer ones with Bang & Olufsen I believe.

There have been several questions asked for the latter:

- [How to fix bad quality sound (Bang & olufsen) on HP envy 13](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1019486/how-to-fix-bad-quality-sound-bang-olufsen-on-hp-envy-13)
- [Subwoofer and Bang&Olufsen speakers not working in HP envy 14-j107tx](https://askubuntu.com/questions/952188/subwoofer-and-bangolufsen-speakers-not-working-in-hp-envy-14-j107tx)
- [How to make subwoofer work in Ubuntu](https://www.andreagrandi.it/2013/06/22/how-to-make-subwoofer-work-in-ubuntu/)
- [subwoofer sound preferences problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53802/subwoofer-sound-preferences-problem)

  ..and many more

---

**What do I know?**
Maybe it can be fixed with HDAJackRetask GUI from `alsa-tools-gui` package(according to the reddit thread). I don't know the remapping for my particular laptop.
There are two front speakers powered from motherboard and two back speakers powered by separate amplifier. The speakers powered by the amplifier don't work.

The closest I've been to it is with [this bug report](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=189331). 2 years and still not a fix by HP. Shame. But there are some workarounds to be found in the thread(also including the mute LED which doesn't work by default). Totally worth having a look.

My personal laptop is HP Pavilion x360 Convertible 14-ba074TU with ALC295.

If someone has any knowledge related to the topic, please share.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/990412/900922 this answer solved disorted sound problem in my laptop.

Comment: any update here?

Comment: @MpizosDimitris nothing yet. :(

Comment: Have you had a chance to try answer below?

Answer (score 1):

I think I might have solved it (Bass Speaker visible in ALSAMixer) on my HP Pavilion x360 with the dreaded ALC295 codec.

Install the `alsa-tools` package if you haven't already: `sudo apt install alsa-tools`

Create this script file at `/usr/local/bin/fix_headphones_audio.sh`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    DEVICE=`ls /dev/snd/hwC[[:print:]]*D0 | head -n 1`
    if [ ! -z "$DEVICE" ]; then
        hda-verb "$DEVICE" 0x20 SET_COEF_INDEX 0x67
        hda-verb "$DEVICE" 0x20 SET_PROC_COEF 0x3000
        break
    fi
    sleep 1
done
```

Then create the systemd service file at `/etc/systemd/system/fix_headphones_audio.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Fix headphones audio after boot & resume.
After=multi-user.target suspend.target hibernate.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/sh '/usr/local/bin/fix_headphones_audio.sh'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target suspend.target hibernate.target
```

After all of this is done, run `sudo systemctl start fix_headphones_audio` and `sudo systemctl enable fix_headphones_audio`. Try suspending and resuming your laptop and play something. Audio should no longer be distorted.

Now, if you were successful in fixing your crackling audio issue, we can move on to enabling the bass speaker:

Edit `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa_base.conf` and add this line:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=alc295-hp-x360
```

Run `sudo update-initramfs -u` to update the initramfs with the new modprobe configuration.

Reboot your laptop and everything should be working.

(Crackling sound fix courtesy of Erikas: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ASUS_Zenbook_UX430#Headphones_audio_is_too_low)

If you found this answer useful, please go to Launchpad and confirm my issue so the developers can fix it upstream: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1874051

Comment: I'm not aware of this crackling sound in my Laptop, HP-15-bc451ns with Ubuntu 20.10 Kernel 5.8.0-33. But I have realized the Orange LED for Mute was not working and probably the Bass Speaker under the Laptop (i have never heard it), so I have added the option in the alsa_base.conf and now the LED works, but I think the Bass Speaker is still not working or at least super low, because I can hear it (even approaching my ear under the laptop). How do you test it?

Comment: Hi, I have the internal speakers low-volume issue in Pavilion 15 ec2xxx. Would be nice if you can help me with it @jkelol11 . Thanks. It is a Ryzen 5600H processor with Nvidia Geforce GTX 1650.