# Ubuntu 20.04 has poor sound quality but Windows dual-boot sounds fine

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, sound, pulseaudio

As the title says, my audio sounds flat on Ubuntu but fine on Windows. It's also much quieter on Ubuntu.

It sounds fine through headphones.

edit: I thought it was missing bass but after testing it on both they're actually about the same

I've tried adjusting Alsamixer, it looks like everything is how it should be [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxR5N.png)

I've tried PulseEffects and PulseAudio to alter the sound quality with no success. PulseAudio will increase the audio but distorts it.

and I've tried adjusting `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` the way described here: [xUbuntu 16.04 no bass and poor sound quality](https://askubuntu.com/questions/865853/xubuntu-16-04-no-bass-and-poor-sound-quality). I think this did help improve the quality a little.

```bsh
$ lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"

00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)  
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio  
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 136  
    Memory at b1328000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]  
    Memory at b1310000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]  
    Capabilities: <access denied>  
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel  
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl  

$ sudo aplay -l  

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****  
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3227 Analog [ALC3227 Analog]  
  Subdevices: 1/1  
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0  
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]  
  Subdevices: 1/1  
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0  
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]  
  Subdevices: 1/1  
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0  
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]  
  Subdevices: 1/1  
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0  
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]  
  Subdevices: 1/1  
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0   
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]  
  Subdevices: 1/1   
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0  


~$ pacmd list-sinks | grep sample  
    sample spec: s32le 2ch 96000Hz

~$ cat /etc/pulse/daemon.conf  

; daemonize = no  
; fail = yes  
; allow-module-loading = yes  
; allow-exit = yes  
; use-pid-file = yes  
; system-instance = no  
; local-server-type = user  
; enable-shm = yes  
; enable-memfd = yes  
; shm-size-bytes = 0 # setting this 0 will use the system-default,   usually 64 MiB  
; lock-memory = no  
; cpu-limit = no  

; high-priority = yes  
; nice-level = -11  

; realtime-scheduling = yes  
; realtime-priority = 5  

; exit-idle-time = 20  
; scache-idle-time = 20  

; dl-search-path = (depends on architecture)  

; load-default-script-file = yes  
; default-script-file = /etc/pulse/default.pa  

; log-target = auto  
; log-level = notice  
; log-meta = no  
; log-time = no  
; log-backtrace = 0  

 resample-method = src-sinc-medium-quality  
; avoid-resampling = false  
; enable-remixing = yes  
; remixing-use-all-sink-channels = yes  
; remixing-produce-lfe = no  
; remixing-consume-lfe = no  
; lfe-crossover-freq = 0  

; flat-volumes = no  

; rescue-streams = yes  

; rlimit-fsize = -1  
; rlimit-data = -1  
; rlimit-stack = -1  
; rlimit-core = -1  
; rlimit-as = -1  
; rlimit-rss = -1  
; rlimit-nproc = -1  
; rlimit-nofile = 256  
; rlimit-memlock = -1  
; rlimit-locks = -1  
; rlimit-sigpending = -1  
; rlimit-msgqueue = -1  
; rlimit-nice = 31  
; rlimit-rtprio = 9  
; rlimit-rttime = 200000  

 default-sample-format = s24le  
 default-sample-rate = 96000  
; alternate-sample-rate = 44100  
; default-sample-channels = 2  
; default-channel-map = front-left,front-right  

; default-fragments = 2  
; default-fragment-size-msec = 125  
; resample-method = speex-float-5  
; enable-lfe-remixing = no  
; high-priority = yes  
; nice-level = -11  
; realtime-scheduling = yes  
; realtime-priority = 9  
; rlimit-rtprio = 9  
; rlimit-rttime = -1  
; daemonize = no  

; enable-deferred-volume = yes  
deferred-volume-safety-margin-usec = 1  
; deferred-volume-extra-delay-usec = 0
```

Update:

I edited the settings according to the recommendation here under 5 Audiophile Pulse User: https://kodi.wiki/view/PulseAudio and audio quality improved but still sounds flat.

The settings changed were:

```
default-sample-format = s24le
default-sample-rate = 44100
alternate-sample-rate = 48000
;new with pulseaudio 11
avoid-resampling = true
resample-method = speex-float-5
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the diagnostic and troubleshooting information you obtained from the question you linked. Specifically `pacmd list-sinks | grep sample` and `cat /etc/pulse/daemon.conf`

Comment: Thank you, I updated my post

Comment: Try changing the `default-sample-format` to `s32le`. Can you also provide some information about your speakers?  How many actual speakers do you have?  Do you have a left and right speaker?  Or more?  Is there a dedicated LFE (sub) speaker? Run `pulseaudio -k` to restart the service after you make changes to the config.

Comment: changing it to s32le yields: ```E: [pulseaudio] daemon-conf.c: [/etc/pulse/daemon.conf:81] Invalid sample format 's23le'. ``` There are two actual speakers, left and right

Comment: `s32le` ≠ `s23le` - fix this typo and make sure you did not make any others

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it, audio sounds the same